# What does "O'Doul" refer to in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, nouns

In the latest episode of the sitcom *The Big Bang Theory*, there was this joke:

> I’ve got a lab full of alcoholic monkeys and tomorrow is the day we switch ‘em to O’Doul’s.

I can't really understand the joke, because I don't know what or who O'Doul is. I tried googling, but all I got was a baseball player named Lefty O'Doul, which doesn't help me in understanding the joke.

Comment: Capitalization clearly indicates it's a proper noun. A proper noun could be just about anything -- not about the English language.

Comment: @Kris - agreed - "too localised", imho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***O'Doul's*** is an (almost) non-alcoholic beer (0.5% alcohol). Not that this makes the joke extremely hilarious, but there you go :)

Comment: I don't find _all_ their jokes funny, but I remember there were lots of laughters after this one, and the review I was reading said it was one of the best lines of the show. Weird, but thank you for the explanation!

Comment: http://www.odouls.com/home.html - in case anyone is interested.

Comment: Also, just because, here's someone else getting a laugh off of O'Doul's http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Csvgp95jO2w